# Services dependency and interaction in Twisted Python

Tags: python, service, twisted

while working on Twisted, I was wondering if there is:

1. a way to explicitly define services dependencies (e.g. in order to start service B, before I need to fire service A)
2. a "pythonic" way to make two services communicate (e.g. B shares information with A, A can control B execution)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Twisted Application Documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html). It sounds like you want to create a `MultiService` each with its own sub-Service implementation. What you do is define a number of services, implementing a `startService` and `stopService` and arrange your services in a tree hierarchy (via `setServiceParent`) to determine arbitrary startup and shutdown orderings.

If you're more interested in distributed service coordination, then that is slightly more difficult. This is something `Erlang` excels at, though if you're not averse to using a system like [Zookeeper](http://hadoop.apache.org/zookeeper/) that could be a solution.

As to your final point, there are a number of ways for services to communicate. You can use something like [Perspective Broker](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-intro.html) for object communication, or go for something more heavy and generalized like [RabbitMQ](http://rabbitmq.com)