# Execute asynchronous code in Twisted *before* start of service

Tags: python, twisted

I start my twisted application with:

```
application = twisted.application.service.Application('myserv')
my_service = MyService()
my_service.setServiceParent(application)
my_factory = twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory()
my_factory.protocol = MyProtocol
twisted.application.internet.TCPServer(port, my_factory).setServiceParent(application)

class MyService:
    def startService(self):
        #only synchronous code here?
```

Before this service can accept client tcp connections, I need to establish a connection to a redis server, that involves execution of asynchronous code. I want to use `d=txredisapi.Connection()`  or alternatively `d = yield txredisapi.Connection()` with `inlineCallbacks` . This deferred must fire before the service can start (before the client's tcp connections are accepted). What is the best place to initiate `txredisapi.Connection()`? Ideally I want to put it in `MyService` class.

Comment: related: [Services dependency and interaction in Twisted Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5287142/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Just write function in toplevel that creates Redis connection and passes it to MyService.
Services may be added in asynchronous code.

```
application = twisted.application.service.Application("myserv")

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def startApp():
  rc = yeld txredisapi.Connection()
  my_service = MyService(rc)
  my_service.setServiceParent(application)
  my_factory = twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory()
  my_factory.protocol = MyProtocol
  twisted.application.internet.TCPServer(port, my_factory).setServiceParent(application)

startApp()
```

Comment: Is there a way to set up Redis connection in `MyService` class? I was hoping something like `addSystemEventTrigger('before','startup'...)` might work?

Comment: You cannot set it in constructor with inlineCallbacks (AFAIK constructors do not play with inlineCallbacks, but you may try).  But you may store Redis' Deferred in MyService constructor, and then call `my_service.setServiceParent(application)` in deferred's callback.  You may write method for it, passing `application` as argument.